# How can I implement a binary search over a list of file names?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, binary

NOTE: Assignment help, No code required.

I have a list of file names in a list-box. As part of the assignment I want to search the file names using a binary search implementation.

Can someone help me understand how to implement a binary search without using the built-in `List<T>.BinarySearch(...)` method?

Comment: what u want to do with searched file? Do you need the file index or name?

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried?

Comment: do binary search without doing binary search? I don't get it :)

Comment: +1 for noting about assignment help.

Comment: Check: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNVCJj642n4

Comment: @GeraldSv: I assume that he's trying to reimplement [`Array.BinarySearch Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah the assignment requires us to create a binary search method, which were not allowed to use  the C# List<T>.BinarySearch function

Comment: Note: Presume the lsit is already sorted

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can only find information about  C# List<T>.BinarySearch function. Ive tried looking through text books but nothing

Comment: @KevinChun: You can have a look at the implementation with `ILSpy`, you'll find it in `ArraySortHelper`(note that `List<T>.BinarySearch` also uses [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx)). But   _"binary search is surprisingly hard to write correctly"_ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256430/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter: haha. yeah i thought so. I might just use the .BinarySearch and lose some marks, I havent had much practice with C# programming so i might not be able to implement the method of that complexity into my assignment

Answer (score 1):

You have to begin with a sorted list of values. Then you just search like you would if you were playing a number guessing game (and were a computer). Pick the middle element of your list. If the number you're searching for isn't equal to the value of the middle element, do the same thing again, but this time on a sub-list that's half the size (since the list is sorted, you know what side of the list your target is on). Just keep doing that until you found the value you're looking for.

Comment: But however the file nmes are string values, is there any possible way to convert string to int?

Comment: To be honest I don't know c#. But it looks like string.Compare() should work. Or you could compare individual characters to one another.

Comment: mmmmmmmm that sounds like an idea! i suppose ill give it ago, thanks for the suggestion